# how to override default region code in "PhoneNumberKit"?

Tags: swift, xcode, phonenumberkit

i'm using the library "PhoneNumberKit"
to format a UITextfield i'm using on my app that i use it to input phone number.

i am using PartialFormatter to format the input into a phone number mask style.

```
@IBAction func onPhoneNumberChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        if (phoneNumberTextField.text?.count ?? 0 < 15) {
            phoneNumberTextField.text = PartialFormatter().formatPartial(phoneNumberTextField.text ?? "")
        } else {
            phoneNumberTextField.deleteBackward()
        }


    }
```

my problem is that it always format the string to a LOCAL phone number, i want to force it to format it into a US phone number mask.

the library say:

```
The default region code is automatically computed but can be overridden if needed.
```

but doesn't give any examples on force region code to be to a specific country

here is the library i'm using: 
https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

does someone here has any exmaples on how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: I can see you answer in the link you provided. Did you read it?

Comment: @Desdenova they dont have it there, instead of doing -1 to my question u could just post what u think the correct answer is.

Comment: Yes they do have it, and I see that you've finally found it. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

fixed it by doing:

```
    phoneNumberTextField.text = PartialFormatter(phoneNumberKit: PhoneNumberKit(), defaultRegion: "US", withPrefix: true).formatPartial(phoneNumberTextField.text ?? "")
```

Answer (score -1):

The default region code is automatically computed but can be overridden if needed like given below

```
class MyTextField: PhoneNumberTextField {
    override var defaultRegion: String {
        get {
            return "US"
        }
        set {} // exists for backward compatibility
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit)